# scope with javascript functions

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to pass I into the inputItems[i].on so i can set it to do a specific task (defined by createSelectedInputItem(i)), how do you pass the variable i into the function() { ..operation here }?

```
for(var i=0; i< 6; i++){
    console.log("setting mouse event for : " + i);

    // Bring in all the input items
    inputItems[i].on('click', function() {

      console.log("i is still:" + i );
      input.tween.reverse();
      console.log("pressed" + i);
      createSelectedInputItem(i);

      for(var j=0; j< 6; j++){
        inputItems[j].tween.reverse();
      } 
    });
  }
```

LOG

//When the page is loaded

```
setting mouse event for : 0

setting mouse event for : 1 

setting mouse event for : 2 

setting mouse event for : 3 

setting mouse event for : 4 

setting mouse event for : 5
```

//When pressing one of the inputItems

i is still:6

```
pressed6
```

this isnt even suppose to exist

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that of **closures**, which are a slightly non-intuitive aspect of Javascript's scoping.

Consider how many variables you have there. How many times does the variable `i` exist? The answer is "as many times as there are scopes that define `i`". In this case, that means there is only one variable `i`, which is referred to throughout your code.

You do a loop with `i`:

```
for(var i=0; i< 6; i++){
```

After this loop has completed (which happen before you do any clicks), `i` is `6`. It will never change again, and it will never refer to any other number.

So the click handler fires, and this line of code is run:

```
console.log("i is still:" + i );
```

`i` is the same variable, and it will therefore be the value `6`.

The way around this is to introduce a new variable for each iteration of the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    (function (innerI) { // create a function with an argument called innerI
        console.log("setting mouse event for : " + i);

        // Bring in all the input items
        inputItems[innerI].on('click', function () {
            console.log("i is still:" + i);
            console.log("innerI is: " + innerI);
            input.tween.reverse();
            console.log("pressed" + innerI);
            createSelectedInputItem(i);

            for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                inputItems[j].tween.reverse();
            }
        });
    }(i)); // invoke the function with i as the argument
}
```

In this code, we create an anonymous function. The function takes one argument, `innerI`. We then immediately invoke that function, and pass `i` as the argument. This creates a new scope and a new variable, so it is not changed when `i++` happens at the end of the loop.

Comment: Ahh this makes so much such, the fact that nothing can change the innerI variable is what makes it work. THANKS :D

Comment: @DarylRodrigo Note that my code is practically the same as Ixe's, except that mine calls the new variable `innerI` rather than `i`. Both are valid, but I find it confusing to have multiple variables with the same name in nested scopes.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputItems[i].on('click', function() {
    // By the time this runs, any variable outside its scope may change,
    // which in this case is 'i' which runs in a loop.
});
```

You should capture the `i` by wrapping it like this:

```
(function(i) {
    inputItems[i].on('click', function() {
        // Now i is an argument to the wrapping closure
        console.log(i);
    });
})(i);
```